# How do I make one if statement run after the other has run and the button is clicked again?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've tried making `if` statements that activate other `if` statements, but both of them ran at the same time.
I also tried `else if` statements, but that didn't seem to work...
So, how would I make: an `if` statement that activates once the past `if` statement has been run and the button is pressed again.
I hope that makes any sense in y'alls head. The help would be appreciated. :)

```js
let One = true
let Two = false
let Three = false
function right() {
    if (One === true) {
        if (Two === false) {
            document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 1
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = ''
            Two = true
            One = false
        } else {
            if (Three === false) {
                document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 1
                document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = ''
                Three = true
                Two = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I encourage you to write some sample code to demonstrate what is your setup and what is the expected behavior.

Comment: let One = true
    let Two = false
    let Three = false
function right() {
if(One === true){
if(Two === false){
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 1
     document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = ''
Two = true
One = false
} else {
if (Three === false) {
    document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 1
     document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = ''
Three = true
Two = false
}}}}

Comment: That's my code sorry forgot to add it

Comment: Also i forgot I could edit the question. :P

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of putting the code in a comment.

Comment: So, you have a function, that gets called whenever button is clicked. You also have 3 elements with IDs `1`, `2`, and `3`. I see that on first click you're writing "1" into the second element and cleaning the first one, on next click, you cleaning second element and writint "1" to the third one. Are you trying to sequentially move that "1" over the elements? Should it return to the first one after next click?

Comment: Yes i am trying to move it but on on the next click it will go to other spots that I will ad once I figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let state = 1;

function right() {
  if (state === 1) {
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 1;
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = '';
    state = 2;
  } else if (state === 2) {
    document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 1;
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = '';
    state = 3;
  } else if (state === 3) {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 1;
    document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = '';
    state = 1;
  }
}
```

the state variable keeps track of the current state. Each time the right function is called, it checks the value of state and updates the elements accordingly. The state variable is then updated to the next state so that the next if statement will run on the next button click.